# String field with single quotation mark is causing an error when inserting record in table

Tags: c#, sql

I have below code:

```
query = "insert into tblB2B_OrderStatusTopStillInRB (LSRNbr, ShipName, Units, DroppedInRB, EPT, Status, OnTimeStatus, ShipVia, DroppedInRB_Order, RealEPT) ";
query += "values ('"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].LSRNbr + "','"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].ShipName + "',"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].Units + ",'"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].DroppedInRB + "','"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].EPT + "','"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].Status + "','"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].OnTimeStatus + "','"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].ShipVia + "','"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].DroppedInRB_Order + "','"
                    + ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].RealEPT + "')";

cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And I just realized, that when the `ShipName` has a value with a single quotation mark, is causing an error in the insert statement, for instance: `int'l Transp.`

Is there any way to fix that, without removing the single quotation mark from the string?

I was trying using the following but didn't work:

```
cmd.CommandText = @query
+ @ListOrdStatusTopInRB[i].ShipName + "',"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix that, without removing the single quotation mark from the string?

Yes - use parameterized SQL instead. You should *never* use variable values directly in your SQL like this. It can allow [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), cause conversion oddities, and generally make the SQL more confusing to read.

See [the documentation for `SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example of parameterized SQL.

Basically, the idea is that your SQL includes references to parameters, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(Foo, Bar) VALUES (@Foo, @Bar)
```

and then you specify the values for `@Foo` and `@Bar` separately. The values then aren't part of the SQL itself, so it doesn't matter whether or not they contain characters which would have special meaning within the SQL.

Comment: Just so you know, for example when you're testing an `insert` statement manually in SSMS, you specify a single quote using two consecutive single quotes. But for anything that isn't just manual that you're doing, parameters is the approach you should take.