# Syntax error in INSERT statement (access database)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I think I got the insert syntax but I always got this error. When I try different projects that are similar, it works just fine. Can you help me?

```
private void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (idkaryawantxt.Text != "")
        {
            string q = "insert into Table1 (Nama,No_Identitas,Alamat,Lahir,Tanggal_Lahir,Telepon,Divisi,Aktif,Password) values ('" + namakaryawantxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + identitastxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + alamattxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + lahirtxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + tgllahirtxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + tlpntxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + divisitxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + aktiftxt.Text.ToString() + "','" + passwordtxt.Text.ToString() + "')";

            dosomething(q);

        }
    }

    private void dosomething(String q)
    {
        try
        {

            connect.Open();
            command.CommandText = q;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();


            loaddata();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            connect.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }


    //REFRESH
    private void loaddata()
    {
        datakaryawan.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        datakaryawan.Rows.Clear();
        datakaryawan.Refresh();


        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\C# Project\minor\Karyawan.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

        connect.Open();



        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1";

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            datakaryawan.Rows.Add();

            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["ID_Karyawan"].Value = reader[0].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Nama_Karyawan"].Value = reader[1].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["No_Identitas"].Value = reader[2].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Alamat"].Value = reader[3].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["PoB"].Value = reader[4].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["DoB"].Value = reader[5].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Telepon"].Value = reader[6].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Divisi"].Value = reader[7].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Aktif"].Value = reader[8].ToString();
            datakaryawan.Rows[datakaryawan.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Password"].Value = reader[9].ToString();
        }




        connect.Close();

        idkaryawantxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        namakaryawantxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        identitastxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        alamattxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        lahirtxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        tgllahirtxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        tlpntxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        divisitxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        aktiftxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        passwordtxt.Text = datakaryawan.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: First thing to do: stop putting the values straight into your SQL. Use parameterized SQL instead. That *may* fix the problem, and it will certainly make it easier to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word PASSWORD is reserved for MS-Access databases.
If you want to use it you need to encapsulate it in square brackets

```
 string q = @"insert into Table1 (Nama,No_Identitas,Alamat,Lahir,Tanggal_Lahir,
              Telepon,Divisi,Aktif,[Password]) values (.....)";
```

said that keep in mind that string concatenation to form a sql command is a bad practice and should be avoided at all costs using a parameterized query.

The worst problem with string concatenation to build sql commands is the possibility of [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326563/string-field-with-single-quotation-mark-is-causing-an-error-when-inserting-recor#19326598) attacks, but also strings that contain single quotes, dates and floating point values are a  problem when you need to use their values to build a string concatenated query text.

For example, what happens if one of your text fields contains a single quote typed by your user?. Another syntax error because when you concatenate a string containing a quote you break the required syntax for the command.

So there is no other acceptable way than use a parameterized query

```
 string q = @"insert into Table1 (Nama,No_Identitas,Alamat,Lahir,Tanggal_Lahir,
              Telepon,Divisi,Aktif,[Password]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 using(OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(.....))
 using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, connect)
 {
     connect.Open()
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", namakaryawantxt.Text);
     ... so on for the other 8 parameters
     ... REMEMBER TO ADD THEM IN THE SAME ORDER OF THE PLACEHOLDERS ...
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: ah my bad I forgot to add, password in here is text type. But Tanggal_Lahir(dateofbirth) and Aktif are in date and time type, Do you think I got wrong in there?

Comment: Always use a parameterized query and leave the job of quoting to the framework code. It knows better

Comment: It helps Steve and also Jon Skeet, next time I'm gonna use parameterized query. Thank you very much for the trouble.

Comment: Quick fix: `string q = ... + "'" + x.ToString().Replace("'","''") + "'," + ...`. But it's still better to parameterized calls.