# Comparison with '{0}' in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql

I have to take over old colleague's code and trying to understand this one SQL statement like below:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date_key = '{0}'
```

Column `date_key`contains `int` values such as `20220712`, `20220120`, etc.

The first guess is that `SELECT` statement filters for rows with `0` value in column `date_key`. However, when running that line of code, I receive this error :

```
SQL Error [100038] [22018]: Numeric value '{0}' is not recognized
```

What exactly does that line of code do?

Comment: Please add a bigger part of the code not just 1 SQL statement.  (I am guessing: Probably `{0}` is being replaced by the value you need?)

Comment: It also looks like it is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: What's the host language? Is the statement part of a prepared query (or similar)?

Comment: @outis The SQL statement is called in an ```cursor.execute``` statement with a ```Snowflake Connector``` in Python (ie. ```import snowflake.connector```)

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [sample code guidelines](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), rather than leaving [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: This question probably needs a [mcve]; currently, it's not complete, as the answer hinges on the python side of the code, possibly [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (particularly as [`Cursor.execute`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#execute) doesn't support any [placeholders](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#label-python-connector-binding-data) matching the `{0}` format, and given the single-quotes around the placeholder).

Comment: @outis You are right. Now that I look at the Python side, it does seems that is a placeholder to be fed with a string. Closing this question.

Comment: @TristanTran: take heed of Mark Rotteveel's comment. There likely is an injection vulnerability, which is completely unnecessary, especially given that Snowflake supports parameters (what it terms ["bindings"](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#label-python-connector-binding-data)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a placeholder, replaced with an actual value in code when calling the query.

See similar [What is {0},{1},{2},{3} in the SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379417/what-is-0-1-2-3-in-the-sql-query)