# How to update data in table datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i used this coding for my update button to update data in my table in datagridview but it is still shows error. i need some help to solve this problem

```
   Dim MyItems As Integer
    Dim MyItemNo As Integer
        Dim ItemDescription As String


        MyItems = GridViewItems.CurrentRow.Index
        MyItemNo = GridViewItems.Item(0, MyItems).Value
        ItemDescription = GridViewItems.Item(1, MyItems).Value

    Dim SqlQuery As String = " UPDATE ITEMS = '" & MyItems & "'WHERE Item_No = " & MyItemNo & ""
        Dim SqlCommand As OleDbCommand


    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()


    End With
```

Comment: Review the syntax of the UPDATE statement

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the [UPDATE sql statement](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_update.asp) is wrong. The correct syntax is

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET <field1> = <value>, <field2> = <value> WHERE <field3> = <value>
```

but there is also the problem of string concatenation that should be addressed.
So you could rewrite your code as

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "UPDATE yourTableName SET ITEMS = ? WHERE Item_No = ?"
Dim SqlCommand As OleDbCommand
With SqlCommand
    .CommandText = SqlQuery
    .Connection = conn
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", MyItems)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", MyItemNo)
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

This is an example of a parameterized query. You should always use this approach when you need to pass values submitted by your user to your database. Without this your code is open to [SQL Injection and other parsing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326563/string-field-with-single-quotation-mark-is-causing-an-error-when-inserting-recor#19326598)